# How to iterate Arraylist<HashMap<String,String>>?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have an ArrayList object like this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

How to iterate through the list?
I want to display the value in a TextView which comes from the data of ArrayList object.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simplest is to iterate over all the `HashMap`s in the `ArrayList` and then iterate over all the keys in the `Map`:

```
TextView view = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.view);

for (HashMap<String, String> map : data)
     for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
         view.append(entry.getKey() + " => " + entry.getValue());
```

Comment: For the 2nd iteration I personally prefer to iterate of the map entries, instead of the keys. `for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())`. That way you already both the key and the value, you don't need another map lookup.

Comment: @BenvanGompel: Good point, depends on your use case, but updated! :)

Answer (score 2):

`for(HashMap<String, String> map : data){
       ... deal with map... 
    }`