# Comparing string between 2 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

I have 2 `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`

1. hashMapFinishedList
2. hashMapUnfinishedList

Both hashMap have same attributes with different values,

I want to make a comparison between these 2 Arraylist, and if it has the same value, than it has to be deleted from the 1st hashmap,

I tried this code :

```
public void compareData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("Location", "Arrive at compareData");
    String a, b;
    Log.d("Status",
            "Total Finished List "
                    + String.valueOf(hashMapFinishedList.size()));
    Log.d("Status",
            "Total Unfinished List "
                    + String.valueOf(hashMapUnfinishedList.size()));
    hashMapFixFinishedList.addAll(hashMapFinishedList);

    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    int size = hashMapFinishedList.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        count++;
        Log.d("Status",
                "Inside Looping FinishedList, Looping "
                        + String.valueOf(count));

        for (int j = 0; j < hashMapUnfinishedList.size(); j++) {
            count2++;
            Log.d("Status", "Inside Looping UnfinishedList, Looping ke "
                    + String.valueOf(count2));
            a = hashMapFinishedList.get(i).get("finishedListId");
            b = hashMapUnfinishedList.get(j).get("unfinishedListId");
            if (a.equals(b)) {
                Log.d("Status", a + " is equal " + b);
                Log.d("Location",
                        "Attempt to remove "
                                + hashMapFinishedList.get(i).get(
                                        "finishedListTitle"));
                if (!(i > hashMapFixFinishedList.size()))
                    hashMapFixFinishedList.remove(i);

            } else
                Log.d("Status", a + " is not equal " + b);
        }
    }
}
```

but it only compares the first hashmap, then the loop doesn't proceed to the next hashmap,

and what concerns me even more is the fact that in my logcat, my program perhaps doesn't loop properly (not really sure though), my hashmap size is 2, and it loops only once.

Here is my logcat,

```
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Location(32341): Arrive at compareData
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Status(32341): Total Finished List 2
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Status(32341): Total Unfinished List 4
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Status(32341): Inside Looping FinishedList, Looping 1
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Status(32341): Inside Looping UnfinishedList, Looping ke 1
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Status(32341): 21 is equal 21
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Location(32341): Attempt to remove Fffgggh
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Status(32341): Inside Looping UnfinishedList, Looping ke 2
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Status(32341): 21 is not equal 44
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Status(32341): Inside Looping UnfinishedList, Looping ke 3
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Status(32341): 21 is not equal 46
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Status(32341): Inside Looping UnfinishedList, Looping ke 4
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Status(32341): 21 is not equal 48
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Status(32341): Inside Looping FinishedList, Looping 2
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Status(32341): Inside Looping UnfinishedList, Looping ke 5
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Status(32341): 46 is not equal 21
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Status(32341): Inside Looping UnfinishedList, Looping ke 6
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Status(32341): 46 is not equal 44
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Status(32341): Inside Looping UnfinishedList, Looping ke 7
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Status(32341): 46 is equal 46
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/Location(32341): Attempt to remove Mau Coba Ah
03-14 17:35:36.195: D/AndroidRuntime(32341): Shutting down VM
03-14 17:35:36.195: W/dalvikvm(32341): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a60c08)
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341): Process: com.thesis.teamizer, PID: 32341
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341):    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:403)
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341):    at com.thesis.teamizer.ViewTaskToDoList.compareData(ViewTaskToDoList.java:180)
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341):    at com.thesis.teamizer.ViewTaskToDoList$AttemptGetTodolist.onPostExecute(ViewTaskToDoList.java:708)
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341):    at com.thesis.teamizer.ViewTaskToDoList$AttemptGetTodolist.onPostExecute(ViewTaskToDoList.java:1)
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
03-14 17:35:36.200: E/AndroidRuntime(32341):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

could you please help me to find the answer, or even the right code?

And Line 180 is `hashMapFixFinishedList.remove(i);`

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

- You can iterate through hash map Using **Iterator** and using **For each** loop
  -Hope it will helpful to you Thanks

```html
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = hashMapUnfinishedList.entrySet().iterator() ;
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator2 = hashMapfinishedList.entrySet().iterator() ;
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry<String, String> obj = iterator.next();
            String comparevalue= obj.getValue();
            //You can remove elements while iterating.
 

  while(iterator2.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry<String, String> obj2 = iterator.next();
            System.out.println(ob2j.getKey() +" :: "+ ob2j.getValue());
            //You can remove elements while iterating.
if(objecomparevalue.equals(ob2j.getValue()))
{
iterator1.remove();
} }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'm kinda new in android programming, iteration like this case http://stackoverflow.com/a/46908/4670114 ?

Comment: yes you can do that or  [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683960/how-to-iterate-arraylisthashmapstring-string this) also. let me know where you get stuck

Comment: Forgive me if I'm asking too much, but it supposed to be like this? 1st loop : for (HashMap<String, String> map : hashMapFinishedList)     2nd loop : for (HashMap<String, String> map2 : hashMapUnfinishedList) {
}, then how could I compare and get string from each hashmap?

Comment: No problem you can ask and yes exactly  you are on right way

Comment: Can you please give me a code example on how to compare all of two hashmaps value using iterator?

Comment: Check my new answer in post

Comment: @JuliusLeo please tellme where you get stuck and can post your code of line with errors thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your hashMapFinishedList size is 2 when you remove 1 value ,then it comes out from the for loop,as the size becomes 1

```
 i < hashMapFinishedList.size(); //and this condition becomes false.
```

thats why it comes out from the loop

Try this way..

```
int size =hashMapFinishedList.size();


 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) //now use this size in your main for loop
```

Hope it works..!

**And in case if you want all data in single hashMap with no duplicate vlues then just create a new Hashmap and**

```
 hashmap.addAll(hashmap1.values());
 hashmap.addAll(hashmap2.values());
```

It will automatically deletes duplicate values.

Comment: You are right, now at least I know what cause the problem, but I still get an error, IndexOutOfBound Exception, because of String A, can you please help me a lil bit? thank you

Comment: do one thing ,create a new hashmap copy of your hashMapFinishedList.,,,,now use   newhashmap.remove(i);  on this new hashmap, and if you still get this problem ,then put this newhashmap.remove(i); inside IF condition if(!(i>newhashmap.size()))

Comment: I tried your code, and it still doesn't work, I've edited my code above to give a better explanation, it still said about indexOutOfBondException,

Comment: try using  for (int i = 0; i <= hashMapFinishedList; i++)  in your very first code

Comment: Then check the size of hash map and before comparing any object please check whether it is null or not.or at that  particular index object exist or not